# Simulated hair isn't affected by force fields?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

I have uploaded a blend file with a "Wind Blowing Hair Test" and it is my hope that perhaps someone can offer some assistance. I utilized a UV Sphere and applied a particle system along with a pair of "Force Fields - Wind" and the hair falls to the bottom of the sphere leaving the top bald while the wind force retains little movement. Any ideas would be great!

Hairtest.blend
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29535

Comment: Good question. I am wondering the same thing. I added collision to the sphere in the Physics panel, and in the modifiers panel I moved it above the hair modifier, but it seems to be the children hair particles colliding with the mesh.

Comment: I have actually managed to get the hair to remain intact and work magnificently while it still needs tweaking to appear professional, real! Some pointers to retain, I believe caution is needed when "Weighting The Hair" while it drastically affected the hair when I reduced the "Strength Gauge" the color changed from red to a darker shade of blue. I didn't utilize the "Physics Tab" in the "Tool Shelf" rather I utilized "Hair Dynamics" in "Properties Tab" within the "Particles Button"

Comment: The gauges are more sensitive than I originally thought and experimenting is a necessity when creating, tweaking hair. I've uploaded my "Test Hair" on a UV Sphere in a blend file for other beginners as myself and the settings allow for "Realistic Hair" in a section I added while in "Particle Mode" and cautiously weighted!
Revisions
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two issues with the wind forces, they are quite weak and they are facing the wrong direction.

The affected axis (under *Falloff*, next to *Power*) was set to -Z (in local coordinates), but the force fields have their positive Z arrows pointing towards the object.

Increase the strength and set the axis to +Z:

[image]

Comment: Hey that is great work!!..Very much appreciated!!